# In Sql Server 2008, can I INSERT multiple rows with some fixed column values and some from a SELECT statement that uses one of the fixed values?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I’m building an insert statement dynamically to add multiple rows of data to a table in a batch, as I believe it is more efficient than inserting one at a time.  However, I need the last couple of columns in each inserted row to be set with the results of querying another table using a value from the new row.  This is my imaginary pseudocode version:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
VALUES (SELECT {value1a}, {value1b}, {value1c}, b.column1, b.column2 FROM TableB b WHERE b.column3 = {value1c}),
       (SELECT {value2a}, {value2b}, {value2c}, b.column1, b.column2 FROM TableB b WHERE b.column3 = {value2c}),
        …
```

Now here is another wrinkle: I have a unique index on TableA with an ignore clause, and there is a lot of redundant data to process, so only about 15% of the rows in any given batch insert will actually be added to the database.  Does this mean it would be more efficient to insert the rows with values for columns 1 – 3, then query for the rows that were inserted, and update column 4 and 5?  If so, would the following be the most efficient way to do that for all the inserted rows?

```
UPDATE a SET a.column4 = b.column1, a.column5 = b.column2 
FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.column3 = a.column3 
WHERE a.CreatedAt >= {BatchInsertTime}
```

(assuming no other processes are adding rows to the table)

Comment: Just remove the `values` - insert *either* with `values` *or* `select`

Comment: For the efficiency question, try them both in SSMS and see what the execution plan says.

Answer (score 1):

For better efficiency and a simpler way to join TableB, send all the TableA rows in a JSON doc, eg

```
insert into TableA (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)       …
select d.*, b.column1 column4, b.column2 column5
from openjson(@json)
  with
  (
    column1 varchar(20),
    column2 int,
    column3 varchar(20)
  ) as d
left join TableB b
on b.column3 = d.column2
```

where @json is an NVARCHAR(MAX) parameter that looks like

```
[
  {"column1":"foo", "column2":3,"column3":"bar" },
  {"column1":"foo2", "column2":4,"column3":"bar2" },
  . . .
]
```

Comment: Sorry, David, I should have specified that the relevant production server is on Sql Server 2008, unfortunately.  I've update the title and tags.

Comment: You can do the same thing with XML in 2008.